# How do I configure my unit tests to run automatically with Elm-Live?

Tags: elm

How do I configure my unit tests to run automatically with Elm-Live?

I currently run elm-live as follows:

```
elm-live Home.elm --open --output=home.js
```

In addition to having automated compilations per modification of my web app, I would also like to ensure that I did not introduce breaking changes as well by having unit tests execute automatically after compiling.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The only point i would make is that elm-test compiles separately from the main elm compiler, so running them at the same time has - for me with my non-elm-live setup - proven rather slow and I abandoned it

Answer (score 3):

You can use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently) to run both processes in the same terminal instance.

The downside is that the stdout will probably not preserve the colors, so reading errors will be a little tricky.

```
concurrently 'elm-live Home.elm --open --output=home.js' 'elm-test --watch'
```

## Example

I've made an [example](https://github.com/halfzebra/elm-live-test) of this setup, check it out on GitHub.

**UPD:** I have updated the example to be Windows-compatible. Apparently, it should have escaped double quotes on the `package.json` instead of single quotes.

Comment: Thanks Halfzebra. However, after I install the "Concurrently" package and attempt to execute the cmd that you provided above, I receive the error:

Comment: The term 'concurrently' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Comment: @ScottNimrod I have added an example for you, check it out!

Comment: Thanks Halfzebra. I updated "package.json" in my solution and attempted to run the script as the readme file states. However, I am still receiving errors.

Comment: my_path\client\app> npm run start:test:watch

> Temp@1.0.0 start:test:watch my_path\client\app
> concurrently 'npm run start' 'npm run test:watch'

[0] 'np' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[0] operable program or batch file.
[1] 'run' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[1] operable program or batch file.
[2] 'start'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @ScottNimrod I have figured it out, please check the example again. The script should use escaped double quotes `\"` istead of `'` to work on Windows.

Comment: Updated but concurrently is still not being recognized even after I installed it.

Comment: PS my_path\client\app> concurrently "elm-live Home.elm --open --output=home.js" "elm-test --watch"
concurrently : The term 'concurrently' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ concurrently "elm-live Home.elm --open --output=home.js" "elm-test -- ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (concurrently:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: @ScottNimrod Please make sure you're running the latest stable [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/)(currently it's v6.11.0) and `npm -v` is `^3.0.0`. You also have to run the `cmd` as an Admin. Can you run the example from GitHub?

I would recommend joining [Elm](http://elmlang.herokuapp.com/) at Slack so that we could look into your issue closely. I have the same nickname there.